# retrive data from firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have array list of coordinates in longitude and latitude both nodes which is child nodes of `ShortestPath_Method_1` I want to extract both longitude and latitude in an array list but cannot find a method how to do it I have attached a code how I was trying to retrieve data and then combining the retrieved  latitude and longitude and after combining putting them in a array list image of database is attached in the link below

```
rootDatabaseref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ShortestPath_Method_1");
        rootDatabaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                latlong.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Double Latitude = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    Double Longitude = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

                    ret = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
                    latlong.add(ret);
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors or didn't you get the data you need ?

Comment: i dont get any error but i didn't get the data in arraylist as combined lat and long

Comment: i was trying to put markers using the  values of latlong array list but it show nothing on the map fragment

Comment: i don't know why this code is not working is i am making any mistake?

Comment: I think you should change the way to store the database. you have to do something like Shortest... -> shortestId -> lat, long

Comment: can't get it what you are saying?

Comment: unpopular opinion: please use Cloud Firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you store the location coordinate like this.

```
- ShortestPath_Method_1
   - shortestUid
      - latitude = 00.000
      - longitude = 00.000
   - shortestUid2
      - latitude = 00.000
      - longitude = 00.000
```

From these, you can call them and store them as an array.

Comment: how can i retrieve them after storing like this

Comment: the same method that you are using right now @VNGamer

Comment: should i retrieve my data in onmap ready function or in oncreate function?

Comment: currently i am trying to extract my data in onMap ready function

Comment: IMO, since you want to display the location on the map, you can put then `onMapReady`. Once the map ready, the database will be called. and then display to the map. @VNGamer

Comment: when i extract my data in onmap ready function using the above code the map activity crash? how can i solve this

Comment: when i remove the above code the map actvity works fine

Comment: if crashed that's mean there will be logcat, can you share the error @VNGamer

Comment: it dont show any error i have a button in map activity  when i press that button map activity will open but when i put the above code in map acivity and click on the button the map activity open and then after few seconds i move back to main activity

Comment: but when i remove the above code then i dont move back in the main activity

Answer (score 1):

Like Ticherhaz pointed out that you should change the design of the database nodes

> Why?

**Reason 1:** Because You have two separate arrays, one for latitude, and the other for longitude, and you need to get one value at a time from both of them, but actually each iteration in the `datasnapshot` can hold one of both arrays, so you need to wait until the entire loop finishes to build up the list, i.e. you can get say the latitude array first and then the longitude array in a serialized order (not in parallel).

**Reason 2:** if the list is big and you want to update list/`RecyclerView` with some of incoming data, you can't until the entire lists come in, and this is bad user experience.

So, you can change the design so that you retrieve a pair of latitude & longitude at a time and add them instantly to the array.

If you still want to solve this, the way you do, you can check the key of the `dataSnapshot` using `.getKey()` and get each list individually and eventually create the object list form both like below:

```
rootDatabaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        latlong.clear();
        ArrayList<Double> latitude = null, longitude = null;

        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

            if (ds.getKey().equals("latitude")) {
                latitude = (ArrayList<Double>) ds.getValue();

            } else if (ds.getKey().equals("longitude")) {
                longitude = (ArrayList<Double>) ds.getValue();
            }
        }

        if (latitude != null && longitude != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < latitude.size(); i++) {
                ret = new LatLng(latitude.get(i), longitude.get(i));
                latlong.add(ret);
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

});
```